# Execute FFMPEG conversion with php

Tags: php, windows, ffmpeg

I've a problem using ffmpeg. From the cmd the command works great but not in php with exec function. (It's a conversion from RTSP (ip camera) to jpg)

**In cmd :** `ffmpeg -i rtsp://user:password@192.168.0.4:554/11 -y -f image2 -frames 1 -t 5 -strict -2 C:/image.jpg`

**so it works fine, i get `image.jpg` in `c:/` :** [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Twpww.jpg)

**code from php :**

```php
<?php
exec('C:/Programmes_meteo/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe ffmpeg -i rtsp://user:password@192.168.0.4:554/11 -y -f image2 -frames 1 -t 5 -strict -2 C:/image.jpg 2>&1', $output);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($output);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

**The result is :** [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/or72L.png)

We can see that ffmpeg works with php but he doesn't execute the code completely.

Does anybody knows the problem ?

PS: OS is windows server 2012

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Remove `ffmpeg`. You already do the command using absolute path to `ffmpeg.exe` (`exec('C:/Programmes_meteo/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe -i rtsp: ... `)

Comment: I LOVE YOU ! now it works! I never thought of that!